# java infinispan the easiest example

Tags: java, persistence, infinispan

I would like to use infinispan (7.0.2.Final) to provide persistency for my server application written in java. Before I started to implement it, I tried the simplest scenario but it did not work...

i.e I implemented two simple unit tests and I run them one after another (i.e. I run them separately).

The first test consisted only of:

```
Cache<Object, Object> c = new DefaultCacheManager().getCache();
c.put("key1", "value1");
```

And the second one:

```
Cache<Object, Object> c = new DefaultCacheManager().getCache();
String result = (String) c.get("key1");
```

but I received result = null ...

What am I doing wrong? I read on infinispan pages that should run out of the box...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your configuration is not clustered. By default, there is used CacheMode=LOCAL and therefore, you can't expect data replication.

Try to set up appropriate cache mode in clustering() element:

http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_configuring_cache_programmatically

Comment: Hmm have you got any link or maybe could you please provide me with the simplest working case? I would be very thankful ;)

Comment: For example Infinispan quickstart for clustered cache: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/clustered-cache

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are expecting persistence (not clustering as @tsykora suggested). The link with programmatic configuration is right, but you'd probably want to use [SingleFileStore](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_single_file_store) (as the simplest persistent store).

```
DefaultCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager();
Configuration c = new ConfigurationBuilder().persistence()
    .addSingleFileStore()
    .location("/tmp/myDataStore")
    .maxEntries(5000);

manager.defineConfiguration("myCache", c);
Cache<Object, Object> cache = manager.getCache("myCache");
```

(code not tested but this is the idea).